# Processing: PImage converting to different type of object when added to ArrayList

Tags: processing

I'm getting a quirky error here.

```
PImage img; 
PImage img2;
PImage img3; 
PImage img4;
PImage img5; 
PImage img6;
PImage img7; 
PImage img8;
PImage img9; 
PImage img10;
int count;
int regionHeight; 
int regionWidth;
ArrayList images; 

void setup(){
  //Image of bottle 
 images = new ArrayList(); 
 img = loadImage("IMG_3763.JPG");
 images.add(img); 
 img2 = loadImage("IMG_3764.JPG");
 images.add(img2);  
 img3 = loadImage("IMG_3765.JPG");
 images.add(img3); 
 img4 = loadImage("IMG_3766.JPG");
 images.add(img4);  
 img5 = loadImage("IMG_3767.JPG");
 images.add(img5); 
 img6 = loadImage("IMG_3768.JPG");
 images.add(img6);  
 img7 = loadImage("IMG_3769.JPG");
 images.add(img7); 
 img8 = loadImage("IMG_3770.JPG");
 images.add(img8);  
 img9 = loadImage("IMG_3771.JPG");
 images.add(img9); 
 img10 = loadImage("IMG_3772.JPG"); 
 images.add(img10); 

 size(img.width, img.height);
 println(img.width); 
}

void draw(){ 
 println(images.get(0).width); 
}
```

It seems that any of the images I put into the array are indeed PImages, which is why I can get img.width in setup(), but when I try to do the same with images.get(index) it returns an Object but that Object is not a PImage. I'm not sure I get why the type has changed, it was my understanding that an ArrayList is like a dynamic array with some extra functionality. It should be returning a PImage object, but processing doesn't treat it as such. I verified this with different functions to try and read more into what gets returned, but it really does seem like a different type of object. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the object as a PImage when you get it from an ArrayList

```
println((PImage)images.get(0).width);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! But just for reference, does this mean that for anything stored in an arraylist I will always have to recast it as a certain type of object, even primitive objects?

Comment: primitives have special objects for this purpose, int = Integer, float = Float... so it would go int((Integer)arrayListOf_ints.get(idx))

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList stores Objects, it does not know the derived types of the Objects it stores, which is why the cast referenced by @bill_automata fixes things.